# How do I use iOS Share Extension to retrieve an image from the Photos App using Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, share, extension-methods

We are developing an app in Xamarin Forms Cross-Platform in C# and need to be able to get a photo from the iOS Photo app.  We have set up a Share Extension, but can't find samples anywhere on how to get the image and the text from the Extension using C#.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well dependency services of course we did something really similar with docs recently and thats the only way i think it is possible

Comment: We already have the share service working for Windows and Android but can't find any C# code samples on how to properly use the Share Extension in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at that [plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) to access media. It's open source so your could adapt it to your exact needs.

Comment: We do use the MediaPlugin but it doesn't seem to cover the Share Extension on iOS.